# Does anyone know if Indonesia is infact allowing foreigners to apply for the short term tourist visa starting from September?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, covid-19, indonesia

I heard in the news that Indonesia is opening up tourism in September and foreigners will be able to apply for the tourist visa in September. However, I can't seem to find any such information on the Indonesian Embassy's website in Germany or any other website that can either confirm or deny the information, which increased my skepticism about the original fact. Does anyone know if Indonesia is infact allowing foreigners to apply for the short term tourist visa starting from September?

Comment: I couldn't find anything anywhere, even on the Indonesian department of foreign affairs web site. Even if this is true you won't be able to apply for several weeks, so check the embassy web sites again in a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know if Indonesia is in fact allowing foreigners to apply for the short term tourist visa starting from September?

No, Indonesian authorities have changed their mind, at least for Bali ([Bali bans foreign tourists for rest of 2020 over COVID-19](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/asia/covid-19-bali-bans-foreign-tourists-for-rest-of-2020-13047688) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200825035914/https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/asia/covid-19-bali-bans-foreign-tourists-for-rest-of-2020-13047688))). Unlikely that some other part of Indonesia opens up in the September or October, unless they try implement some [travel bubbles as Thailand is considering](https://www.thephuketnews.com/phuket-travel-bubbles-may-begin-from-oct-1-77069.php) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200825040156/https://www.thephuketnews.com/phuket-travel-bubbles-may-begin-from-oct-1-77069.php)).